# Rails application support different timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a Blog application using ruby on rails where users can post there blogs.
In this, I wanted to show DateTime when the blog is posted but this should be according to different users' current DateTime. like if I posted a blog from the country `A` so for me it should show my country-specific DateTime but for other users, DateTime should be in their respective time zone. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Too broad to answer here, but a search for "rails time zones" yields stuff [like this](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones). You need to do some research before we can really engage and help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Rails stores dates in UTC and converts them to your computer's timezone after pulling them from the database.

To convert a date into a specific timezone, you can call [`in_time_zone`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Zones.html#method-i-in_time_zone):

```
posted_at = Time.parse('2020-10-07 07:28:31Z')
#=> 2020-10-07 07:28:31 UTC

posted_at.in_time_zone('Asia/Tokyo')        # a user from Tokyo
#=> Wed, 07 Oct 2020 16:28:31 JST +09:00

posted_at.in_time_zone('America/New_York')  # a user from New York
#=> Wed, 07 Oct 2020 03:28:31 EDT -04:00
```